# Screen automatically wakes up with PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE wakeLock

Tags: android

In the following sample activity, the screen automatically wakes up right after the user switches it off (with power button), but only if I use the `PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE` flag. It doesn't happen if I don't use this flag.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    private WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        wakeLock = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "test");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        wakeLock.release();
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour while still using the `PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE` flag ?

I have the same issue when using the MediaPlayer's `setWakeMode()` method (I checked in the source code and it also uses this `PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE` flag)

Or maybe I just misunderstand the purpose of this flag...what is it made for then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after many experiments it seems that there is no way to avoid this auto screen wakeup when using this `PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE`.

As a consequence it's not possible to use `MediaPlayer.setWakeMode()` without having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON) class has a flag, `FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON`.  It's documented as follows:

> Window flag: when set as a window is being added or made visible, once
>   the window has been shown then the system will poke the power
>   manager's user activity (as if the user had woken up the device) to
>   turn the screen on.

Try clearing this flag in your `onResume`:

```
getWindow().clearFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON );
```

and see if that makes the screen stay dark after the power button is hit.   You could experiment with the flag in `onPause` too.  Just a guess.

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately. But thanks for the tip, I'll do some experiments with these WindowManager flags